# Word for Mac: How can you stop a category of Table of Authorities add an extra line after its entry?

Tags: ms-office

I created a few different categories only to realize I missed out one later.

Now I have an option to simply unwind all the changes I made in the text, and rename the top category to the one I should have had in the first place, and then re-mark each citations or I can go with it...

Which means, I have to rename a subsequent category, say, some of the ones numbered and not named to the category I wish. And then simply add that particular category above "all" of the table of authorities as inserted in the text previously. The problem is, it adds an extra line each time the tables are updated.

I am hoping for a solution that will not add automatically a line there.

Is there a way?

Comment: Could you please add more detail to your situation? What version of Word, what version of MacOS, etc. Also a screenshot that shows what you are trying to do or a link to an example file would greatly increase the chance of being able to help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the intent to help, will do now!